# Получить количество входных параметров

Tags: mysql

В моей MySQL базе данных есть различные хранимые процедуры с входными параметрами и без них. Как изнутри этих процедур получить количество принимаемых ими параметров?

Comment: Где Ваш пример реализации? SO не фриланс биржа

Comment: @DaemonHK Думаю ТС имел ввиду "написать за него", а подсказать откуда взять количество параметров. И какаую реализацию вы хотите увидеть у автора вопроса, если писать абсолютно не чего, пока не знаешь откуда взять информцию

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для решения задачи необходимо иметь права на чтение из таблицы `mysql.proc`. В этой таблице есть поле `param_list`, которое содержит определение параметров процедуры или функции. Т.к. Вам нужно узнать количество, то Вам нужно подсчитать количество запятых в этом поле и прибавить 1. Считать можно при помощи последовательных вызовов функции `LOCATE()`

В коде это выглядит так

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'127.0.0.1' FUNCTION sf_i_prm_cnt(
        in_db VARCHAR(64),
        in_name VARCHAR(64),
        in_is_proc BOOLEAN
    )
    RETURNS int(10) unsigned
    DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_params BLOB;
  DECLARE var_res INTEGER UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE var_pos INTEGER UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    RETURN NULL;

  SELECT
    TRIM(p.`param_list`)
  FROM
    mysql.proc p
  WHERE
    p.`db` = in_db AND
    p.`name` = in_name AND
    p.`type` = IF(in_is_proc, 'PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION')
  INTO
    var_params;

  IF (var_params IS NOT NULL AND var_params <> '') THEN
    REPEAT
      SET var_pos = LOCATE(',', var_params, var_pos + 1);
      SET var_res = var_res + 1;
    UNTIL (var_pos = 0) END REPEAT;
  END IF;

  RETURN var_res;
END;
```

Comment: Изначально я так и хотел сделать, но почему-то, вместо списка параметров, мне возвращается BLOB.

Comment: @hmeli7 Да. Вот его и нужно распарсить

Comment: @hmeli7 Я написал Вам функцию

Comment: Спасибо, пол дня "голову ломал"